# Breaking on user input without delay in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a while loop that reads from a **socket**, and instead of a **timer**, I want to break, close the socket and end the program on user input, but I don't want the user to have to enter a "1" or "continue" or "something" for each reading. I just want if there is input from the user, break and close, otherwise, if there is no interference, continue.
I am afraid I am going to have to use a **timer**, which I don't want to do because it would delay receiving from the socket, and I need to have little or no delay if possible.

Is there some Java function that does this or a simple solution I am missing?

**EDIT:**

I don't want to wait for the user input. I just want to continue unless user input is detected, but the point is that there is no delay in checking to see if the user has entered something. I am going on the program assuming that it should simply continue until the user says otherwise.

Comment: And do you want to give the user some time to make a deсision?

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what you want to do. I'm quite confused at the moment. You say "I just want if there is input from the user, break and close, otherwise, if there is no interference, close." So you want to close in both cases but break from the while loop as well if there is no more input?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have worked out that you want to specify a timeout period? You can set a timeout by calling on the Socket the method `setSoTimeout(int timeout)`, you can also specify it through the Socket constructor. See [Socket API here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know I can set a timeout, but I don't want the program to end at a certain time, it has to be completely dependent on when the user wants it to end. In this case, the user wouldn't know at the start of the program how long it should run.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is probably to start a thread running which awaits user input. if this is detected then the thread can set a flag which is checked inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about binding a event listener to your input, and if there is a input you handle it(in this case close the socket connection)

You have a "similar" sample [here](http://www.ashishmyles.com/tutorials/tcpchat/index.html)

EDIT: Didnt fully read your question. Thought you hade some kind of GUI. Since you dont then you coudl do something like this (havent use threads in a while in Java so this is "pseudocode" but i hope you get tthe picture):

```
public void start()
{
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console != null)
        {
                Thread th = new Thread(yourWorkerClass);
                th.run();

                //blocking
                String readLine = console.readLine("Do something: ", (Object[])null);
                th.stopYourWorkMethod(); 

        }
}
```

Comment: Does that work without any GUI? I am (at the moment) only writing a command line program. Although if this eventually becomes a GUI I will surely use that.

Answer (score 1):

You need Threading for your requirement. Open a new thread that reads from socket while in your main thread you wait for user input. When you get the input you can interrupt your other thread.

You can do a Thread class such as:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {
    private String address;
    private int port;

    ClientThread(String address, int port) {
        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        // connect to socket and start reading
        . . .
    }
}
```

And then use it in your application with:

```
ClientThread c = new ClientThread("127.0.0.1", 4547);
c.start();
```

Comment: That sounds good, but I would like to get the port number (and possible IP address) from the user in the main program, then open the socket Listener thread. How do I send that information to that thread, or am I thinking about it wrong (I haven't worked with threads much at all)?

Comment: @Cat added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an isReady on the input stream to see if there is any data there. In the simplest case, you could sleep for the specified time, then check isReady, and proceed or abort as required. If you want to respond immediately when the user sends the cancel signal, you could have a loop that keeps checking isReady and checking the current time against a starting time, and breaks when either condition is met. If there's some other work that you want to do while waiting for this to happen, you could put it in a separate thread. (In which case the loop should include a yield() to let other things happen.)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want two threads.

One thread should read user input and put that "command" in a variable that is shared with another thread.

The second thread should process "commands" from that variable (you probably want a queue of commands being built). That thread should wait for commands being placed in the queue.

The variable (probably a queue) holding the commands should be protected by a synchronized block. The second thread should wait() on the object that is being synchronized on and the first thread should run notify() on that object when it has placed a command there.

Then the second thread can process commands and react to them without having to wait for user input (as long as there are commands to process) and be immediately woken up when there is something to do.